# How to: Connect Admin Panel (like SB Admin 2) with HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working with WordPress with 3+ years. I have experience in js, html5, css3 for more than 1 year. 
Now i want to build my own template. Mobile responsive, and what not.

I want that template to have an admin panel. I found out that there are a lot of free admin panels, I just never found a tutorial on how to use them.

Any tips, hints, links from tutorials are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at [CouchCMS](http://couchcms.com)? I've used it before for a simple site where WordPress would be too much. They also have a lot of [documentation](http://docs.couchcms.com/)!